# I am not sure what this prefix hash method is supposed to do?

Tags: c++, hash, collision-detection

What are prefix hash functions used for? I have created chaining, quadratic, and linear hash tables. I was given simples, prefix, and full-length hash methods which i am not sure what they are used for??

Here is the code:

```
int HashTable_qp::preHash(string & key, int tableSize )
{
    string pad = "AA";
    //some words in the input are less than 3 letters
    //I choose to pad the string with A because all padded characters 
    //have same ascii val, which is low, and will hopefully alter the results less
    if (key.length() < 3)
    {
        key.append(pad);
    }
    return ( key[0] + 27 * key[1] + 729 * key[2] ) % tableSize;
}
```

collision detection:

```
while(i != DataArray.size())
{
    tStart = clock();

    if(QuadraticProbingHT.preHash(DataArray[i],101) == QuadraticProbingHT.preHash(DataArray[i],101) )
    {
        collision_count++;
    }
    tStop = clock();
    total_c += tStop - tStart;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prefix hash hashes a string by its first few characters (the prefix).

Note that in the implementation you give, it hashes a string using the first three characters (if existent; it pads with `AA` if necessary). Thus, `ass` and `associate` has the same hash value under this specific prefix hash.

A full-length hash uses every character in the string to determine the hash value.

Comment: It's the hash code for the given hash function. Your questions indicate that you might not even understand hash functions at all.

Comment: no i knew that it was returning a hash code but what is the 27 and 729 do? and how could i detect a collision?

Comment: They are just values used to try to get a good distribution of values. Note that 729 = 27^2. This hash function is merely `27^0 * key[0] + 27^1 * key[1] + 27^2 * key[2]`. It's not clear to me that this a good hash function, but that's beside the point. You detect a collision the same way you detect a collision in any hash table: hash the object and see if the bucket that comes up based on the hash code is occupied already.

Comment: so would the collision detection looks something like i posted??

Comment: No. Your conditional is always true (assuming successive calls on the same input to `preHash` give the same output (say, the example implementation you gave)).

Comment: are u saying the conditional would be if (!QuadraticProbingHT.preHash(DataArray[i],101)